# running cmd in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, cmd

I want to run cmd in a asp.net application. Here is my code:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "cd C:\\";
process.Start();
```

The program starts the cmd.exe but instead of "C:>" I see this:

```
C:\program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Devserver\10.0>
```

Could somebody tell me what i do wrong in the code? Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://www.codersbarn.com/post/2011/11/08/Calling-Console-Application-from-Web-Form.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Arguments` are used as the parameters to the application being called, therefore it's the same as having `cmd "cd c:\"` in your Run prompt under the Start Menu.

In this instance, what I think you want is the following (instead of the `Arguments` line)...

```
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "c:\\";
```